# Why don't the Function Key options and play/pause/volume work on a Mac Bluetooth Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, 11.10, bluetooth, apple

I am currently running Ubuntu 11.10 with all updates.

I have been using Ubuntu very successfully on my MacBook Pro (5,5) for a few years now. I also have a Apple bluetooth keyboard. On the laptop keyboard and bluetooth keyboard I can use the extra function keys (volume, play, pause etc) as expected. And I get page up/down with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and start/end with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

The other day I purchased a 2nd Apple bluetooth keyboard for use at work. It appears the same, although perhaps some upgraded components (my 1st one is ~2 years old). However none of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> options work nor the play/pause/volume.

This problem seems to be keyboard specific rather than Ubuntu-wide as I can use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys on my laptop keyboard, while simultaneously being unable to use them on my external bluetooth keyboard.

Any suggestions or ideas about where to start?

I think the bluetooth keyboards are linked to the MacBook Pro range, so perhaps I have the drivers installed for my laptop (MacBook Pro 5,5) and this new keyboard is similar to a newer MacBook Pro for which I don't have adequate drivers.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro 8,2 on which the keyboard's audio keys were working fine in 11.04. When I upgraded to 11.10, they stopped working. I'm looking around the Net to see if I can find a solution, so if I do, I'll stick the answer in here.

Answer (score 1):

The article there should help you.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard

insert the two echo linesin /etc/rc.local:

```
echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
echo 2 > /sys/module/apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Those are inserted just before the "exit 0" line.

I only use Apple keyboards and I found they are easier to manage and configure under Linux than Windows. Also, that's the ONLY hardware I have from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running evtest to see whether they are being recognised by the system. After installation, just run `sudo evtest` and choose the right device corresponding to your keyboard. Then, just press the function keys and check whether there are any events being generated. 
If you see any events being generated, note the names and codes of the keys. If they are obvious ones like KEY_VOLUME_UP or similar, then I'm afraid I can't help. Also, if the codes generated are more than 255, then it won't work since X can't accept keycodes over 255. 
You can also try making a custom keyboard shortcut from the keyboard dialog and check whether that works.